# Ошибка при подключении к БД, как решить проблему?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def users_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?', (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (user_id) VALUES (?)', (user_id,))

    def user_money(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute('SELECT money FROM `users` WHERE user_id = ?', (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return int(result[0][0])

    def add_money(self, user_id, money):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET money = ? WHERE user_id = ?', (money, user_id,))

    def add_check(self, user_id, money, bill_id):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO `check` (`user_id`, `money`, `bill_id`) VALUES (?,?,?)', (user_id, money, bill_id,))

    def get_check(self, bill_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM  `check` WHERE `bill_id` = ?', (bill_id,)).fetchall()   
            if not bool(len(result)):
                return False
            return result[0]

    def delate_check(self, bill_id):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute('DELETE FROM `check` WHERE `bill_id` = ?', (bill_id,))
```

Вот мой код, который должен взаимодецствовать с БД, но он не подключается к нему.
Файл с БД есть с папке с питоновским файлом, все перепроверил в SQLlitestudio.
Сама ошибка: no such table: users
[image: Вот скриншот с БД]

Comment: Путь к файлу с БД абсолютный или относительный? Если относительный, то следует прописать его полностью, может так быть, что создаётся новая БД в другом каталоге

Comment: @ПавелКовтун Путь к файлу абсолютный , по крайней мере я запускаю скрипт так.

Comment: @ПавелКовтун Я также добавил вот такую строчку кода, но это не помогло.
db_file = 'C:\парсинг\disss\Телеграм\shop\database.db'

Comment: Тут вариантов не много, если такая таблица есть, а sqlite пишет, что нет, то это говорит о том, что вы неверно указываете путь к базе данных для подключения

Comment: @ПавелКовтун Проверил путь таблицы и попробовал ее пересоздать, не помогло. С чем еще это может быть связано? Также провел тест соединения в приложении, ответ положительный

Comment: Я написал вам в ответе, что ваш код у меня работает с новосозданной базой, значит очевидно, что проблема не в коде. Всего 2 варианта: 1) В самой БД нет такой таблицы 2) Sqlite не видит БД по указанному вами пути и создаёт по этому пути пустую БД без этой таблицы

Comment: @ПавелКовтун Спасибо за то что протестировали код у себя, попробую еще раз проверить все

Comment: Попробуйте переместить вашу базу из папки со скриптом куда-то в другое место и заново запустить скрипт, в папке должна будет автоматически появиться пустая база, если такого не происходит, то значит путь указан вами неверно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создал новую БД, в ней таблицу `users`, запустил ваш код с моей только что созданной базой - всё отработало успешно.

Вариантов такого поведения у вас не так много, а конкретно - один:

`sqlite` не может подключиться к БД по указанному вами пути и создаёт по этому пути пустую базу без этой таблицы. Происходит это скорее всего из-за того, что некорректно указан путь, самая типовая проблема: указание относительного пути вместо абсолютного, потому что sqlite ищет базу в папке со скриптом.

Что можно посоветовать: проверяйте, что путь к указанной базе соответствует действительности.

Также полезно знать, что в случае отсутствия БД по требуемому пути `sqlite` автоматически создаст пустую БД, можете переместить вашу базу из папки со скриптом и заново его запустить, тогда в папке со скриптом должна будет автоматически создаться пустая база. Если этого не произойдёт, то значит путь указывается неверно.